# Using SSI with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssi

I am developing a web application and I am using Server Side Includes. At one point in my code, I have the following:

```
<div class="overlayer">
    <!--#include virtual="/module/[id]" -->
</div>
```

This include works perfectly, but I need to reload the content of this div dinamically with jQuery. I have tried this so far:

```
$("div.overlayer").load("/module/[another_id]");

$.when($.ajax("/module/[another_id]")).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $("div.overlayer").html(data);
});
```

Both of them load my HTML well, but some of the functionalies of it don't work because the module is not being loaded from server side. Is there any way to use SSI with Javascript?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Are both the http request and the ajax request from the same domain IE are both a https-request?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same domain